# oracle PL/SQL with automatic values

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi folks I have a question regarding calculating the value in a column in oracle.

So I have this table

```
NAME     PROCESS1    PROCESS2    WEIGHT    TOTAL_WEIGHT
ITEM1    0           0           10
ITEM2    1           1           10
ITEM3    1           1           15
```

So what I am trying to do here is generating the value in total_weight based on process1 and process2 in PL/SQL. Because later on I need to show the sum of total weight in PHP page. so for item 2 the total weight should be 20 and for item 3 it should be 30. Should I use procedure for generating the value in total weight? I want the value is updated when user change the value in Process1 or process2. Please help me I am kinda newbie here.

Comment: First, why would the `total_weight` for item 3 be 30 rather than 35 (10+10+15)?  Second, how are you ordering the results in order to have item 1 appear first?  Third, does the `total_weight` ever reset?  Or do you just want the running total over all rows in the result?

Comment: thank you Justin. so that's how the professor wants me to do. for each process we need to increment the weight so the formula is (process1+process2)*weight. well the order doesn't matter because the UI handles it. total_weight will never reset. its value will fluctuate based on process1 and process2

Comment: @Richard Pascual Please provide any reason for an edit in the edit reason field, or if that field is for some reason not suitable, write the reason for the edit as a comment down here, separate from the question. I have approved your edit but removed the comment you put inside the question itself.

Comment: Thanks, [@Lundin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/584518/lundin).  I originally intended to avoid getting my edit comment lost within the sea of comments down here.  I will just repeat what I wrote, but down here instead:  "The OP was tagged originally as [tag:PHP].  I removed this tag as it did not seem relevant to the core of the question.  Although the final use of the table data was for a web page in PHP, the problem at hand centers on `SQL` and the use of `DERIVED (VIRTUAL) VALUES` within an individual SQL query statement or table design DDL script."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Declaring VIRTUAL (Computed) COLUMNS in Oracle Table Design

I'll agree with most of what has been said so far with some additional elaboration.  My starting table design looks similar but it too is also inaccurate for some use cases as explained below.

```
    CREATE TABLE "PROCESSED_PRODUCT_WEIGHT" (
       "PRODUCT_NAME"  VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
       "PROCESS1"      NUMBER,
       "PROCESS2"      NUMBER,
       "WEIGHT"        NUMBER,
       "TOTAL_WEIGHT"  NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
                       ((PROCESS1 + PROCESS2)*WEIGHT) VIRTUAL,
       "RECORDED_DATE" DATE,
       CONSTRAINT  "PROCESSED_PRODUCT_WEIGHT_PK" 
          PRIMARY KEY ("PRODUCT_NAME", "RECORDED_DATE")
       )
       /
```

### Previous Suggestions and Assumptions

***Table Bound Attribute Properties***:  The table construct used by [@Bob Jarvis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213136/bob-jarvis) is also known as a `VIRTUAL COLUMN`.  It works well because the definition of `TOTAL_WEIGHT` is entirely dependent on other values contained within the same table.

***SQL Query Associated Calculation:*** On the other hand, [@Nishanthi Grashia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3492139/nishanthi-grashia) and [@OldProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745544/oldprogrammer) both recommend modifying the value within each SQL query executed against the database.

*BOTH* Cases may work assuming that the mass per unit of the product does not change during the lifetime of the production cycle.

> An example where this assumption is not flexible is if the products consist of units of varying mass per unit volume.
>
> - Since it was not mentioned in the OP, consider this possibility:
> - Products ITEM1, ITEM2 and ITEM3 have variable weights per unit.
> - They are all produced in a coffee packaging plant.
> - Each item can be a type of coffee bean and its source.
> - "Processes" could be bean "treatments" such as decaffeination, roasting type or flavor infusion.

The "units" could be packaging of varying sizes.  This would mean that package volumes would have a direct effect on the mass (called "weight") per product unit counted.

### Test Cases for Identifying the Effect of Changing Unit Sizes

Each test case shows how a virtual column does not satisfy the possibility of variations in the unit sizes and masses of each product over time.

[image: Initial Table Population]

**Test Case One:**

[image: Test Case One: Change Process Quantites for Two Different Item Types]

*For production observations made 2/14/2015*

**Test Case Two:**

[image: Test Case Two: No Process Quantities Counted/Incremented]

*The mass per unit processed on 3/14/2014 is increased only, skewing the total mass produced since the item quantities made previously are multiplied by a larger value through the virtual column definition.*

**Test Case Three:**

[image: Test Case Three: Process Quantity and Mass per Unit Changes]

### Data Output and Results

[image: Result Snapshots for each production period]

*Above are the test results associated with all three test cases.*  the resulting values are not correct for the use cases created.  They demonstrate that for a changing weight value, the virtual/calculated column formula and approach gives incorrect results.

### A Discussion of Alternate Solutions

1. The trigger approach may work for maintaining calculated values for `TOTAL_WEIGHT`.  Incremental changes (updates) are appended to the current, existing value as each component varies.
2. Force all DML through a single DML operation contained in a CRUD package.  The problem with defining an embedded SQL statement to enforce requirements is that other processes and their developers will need to be familiar with what your isolated PHP form/page does within your app in order to duplicate it for their own operation.
3. If there is a concern about overhead or possible locking of the main table, then consider introducing a composite key: `PRODUCT_NAME` + `WEIGHT`.  This covers for the problem so that quantities of the same product name are multiplied by their correct weight and values already calculated remain unchanged even if the weight multiplier is modified.

> `SOMETIMES`, `ALWAYS`, `NEVER`... Are popular assumptions thrown around in developer's project circles.  How likely is this to happen at all?  It depends... if you're a coffee bean packaging outfit, I'd say it's quite possible.

Onward!

Answer (score 4):

```
select name, process1, process2, weight, (process1+process2)*weight total_weight
from table
```

I see no reason that PL/SQL has to play a role in this, unless I misunderstood the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want the field `TOTAL_WEIGHT` to be updated whenever the value in process 1 or process2  changes. So, Ideally you must be using **TRIGGERS** for this.

**TRIGGERS** are used to trigger an action based on an initial event.

So, for your case, the **initial event** is "`Value change of process1 or process2`" and the **action expected** is "`automatic update of total weight field based on changed value`."

But, for your requirement, a trigger is unnecessary and a ***totally unnecessary overhead***. So, instead of having an additional field in the table, rather use a select query as below, which would calculate the value during run-time and display the real-time value.

```
SELECT NAME, 
       PROCESS1,
       PROCESS2,
       WEIGHT ,
       (WEIGHT * (PROCESS1 + PROCESS2)) AS TOTAL_WEIGHT
FROM MY_TABLE
```

The **output** would be:

```
NAME   |  PROCESS1  |  PROCESS2  |  WEIGHT   | TOTAL_WEIGHT
------------------------------------------------------------
ITEM1  |  0         |  0         |  10       |  0
ITEM2  |  1         |  1         |  10       |  20
ITEM3  |  1         |  1         |  15       |  30
```

You can use this TOTAL_WEIGHT using something like `resultSet.getLong("TOTAL_WEIGHT");`

Or, if you are very particular in having the field, then you can modify your update query to include

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE  SET FIELD1=VALUE1, FIELD2=VALUE2, ... ,
TOTAL_WEIGHT = (WEIGHT * (PROCESS1 + PROCESS2))
WHERE SOME_CONDITION;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using 11g or later, the safest way to handle this would be to make TOTAL_WEIGHT a computed column. The CREATE TABLE statement would then become something like

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE
 (PROCESS1      NUMBER,
  PROCESS2      NUMBER,
  WEIGHT        NUMBER,
  TOTAL_WEIGHT  NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (NVL((PROCESS1+PROCESS2)*WEIGHT, 0)));
```

Done this way applications don't need to know how to compute TOTAL_WEIGHT - it's always done correctly.

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8fdaa/1).

Share and enjoy.